# android request JSON response in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, android, http-post

My code don't want to work... 
I know that there are lots of topic about this problem but none of these had helped me....

It is my code about the HTTP POST request

```
class newCommand extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    /**
     * Creating product
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String name = Nom.getText().toString();
        String place;
        String place2;
        if (switchAix.isChecked()) {
            place = "aix";
        } else {
            place = Chambre.getText().toString();
        }

        String date = "cc";
        String nombre = Nombre.getText().toString();
        String garniture = Garniture.getText().toString();
        String regime = Regime.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nom", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("app556hg23", place));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nombre", nombre));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("garniture", garniture));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regime", regime));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date_livraison", date));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+params+"]");
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_crepes_add, "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showFragment(new HomeFragment());


            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/

        return null;
    }
}
```

then it is my code of my PHP sheet

```
include "bdd.php";
require_once 'autoload.php';
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha('6LeAE4cUAAAAAJjH0lbmPNaprtiTgvP4D54myOzU');
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
if ($resp->isSuccess()) {

$reponse = array();

$name = $_POST['nom'];

$query=$bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO crepes(nom) VALUES(:a)');
$query->execute(array(
    'a' => $name
));

if ($query) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}

} else {

}
```

I know that the error occur when the line : JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_crepes_add, "POST", params);
is executed. The android studio software says me : 
E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

Thanks a lot for your anwers

Comment: Can you inspect the raw response in android studio? Whatever the response is, it's not JSON.

Comment: What do you mean by raw response ?
I juste have this error...

Comment: The actual response data returned from the server.  Your android code is throwing that error because it is not able to parse the response as JSON.  If you look at the response, you'll be able to see _why_.  Most likely the PHP is generating an error message that you'll be able to use to debug the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I tried for 4 days... BUT how can I be sure that the server is responding ?